# Is it possible to insert a spacer on the left side of gnu screen?

Tags: gnu-screen, virtual-terminal

Some monitors cut off the leftmost column in a virtual terminal. Is it possible with gnu screen to begin at the second column, so as to not have any cells that are not visible?

I would be interested in any other ways of dealing with this cut off column when using gnu screen.

I am aware of the possibility of a width 1 vertical region on the left. I am looking for something at least a little less cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the screen into 2 parts vertically and adjust the width of the rightmost screen to about 95%.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>|</kbd> to slipt the screen

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to move to right

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to start new terminal on the right

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>:resize 95%</kbd> to make rightmost terminal use 95% of the space.

Adjust the percent value according to your needs.